# Why my email is going to spam folder

Tags: php, mysql, email, spam

```
$result=mysql_query($sql);
if($result)
{
// ---------------- SEND MAIL FORM ----------------

// send e-mail to ...
$to=$email;
// Your subject
$subject="Your confirmation link here";
// From
$header="from: Welcome to gvmgvhgvmhgm <info@hgfgfcjhgv.com>";
// Your message
$message="Your Comfirmation link \r\n";
$message.="Click on this link to activate your account \r\n";
$message.="Welcome to dtnhngg .com .. Make your journey more comfortbale";
$mailedby="mailed-by: jfncghjnhgn.com";

// send email
$sentmail = mail($to,$subject,$message,$header,$mailedby);
if($sentmail){
echo "Your Confirmation link Has Been Sent To Your Email Address.";
}

die(mysql_error());

mysql_close();

?>
```

> i m using this code to send mail ... But my mails are going directly to the spam folder .. Any help regarding this ???

Comment: Is your mail server an authorized smtp sender, i.e do you have spf record setup for the mail server?

Comment: how can i knw dt @Chelseawillrecover ?

Comment: are you sending to an external email address? are you sending via an SMTP server or exchange server or ??

Comment: i m sending mail to a personal gmail address ... @Chelseawillrecover

Comment: Check the message header and look for things like this: X-Proofpoint-Spam-Details: rule=notspam policy=default score=0 spamscore=0 ipscore=0 suspectscore=22
 phishscore=0 bulkscore=0 adultscore=0 classifier=spam adjust=0 reason=mlx

Comment: Also this: Received-SPF: Fail

Comment: should i update my header to this ??

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that your e-mail contains the right headers (like `MIME-Version` and `Content-Type`). 
Furthermore, since you're sending a HTML e-mail, you should include a full HTML document in `$message` with `<!DOCTYPE>`, `<html>`, `<body>` and so on.

The spam-filter might be giving your e-mail a higher spam-rating because of these issues.

After that, if you still have problems, check [Why is my e-mail still being picked up as spam? Using mail() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515769/why-is-my-e-mail-still-being-picked-up-as-spam-using-mail-function) as @Amal Murali suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to headers

```
$headers  .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

Comment: $header="from: Welcome to Eciticket <info@eciticket.com>";    should i update it or where should i put it ??

Comment: $header="From: Welcome to Eciticket <info@eciticket.com>\r\n";
$headers  .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

Comment: $sentmail = mail($to,$subject,$message,$header,$mailedby);     i ve to update this 1 also ??

Comment: yes, mail($to,$subject,$message,$header,$mailedby) is a mail sending function

Comment: YEAH i knw that.. bt its giving me an undefined index headers error ....

Comment: Remove <info@eciticket.com> From main header and try

Comment: same same :( @ganesan

Comment: You will get lots of suggestions, but you have to do your own investigation by checking the message header which will give you much better idea why the mail was marked as suspected spam