# Why is my php email script sending an email to my spam not in my inbox

Tags: php, ajax

Here is my php code below. When I click "send email" button it works fine. But it doesn't appear to my Inbox. It was routed to Spam folder:

```
<?php 

  function sendmail(){

        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $name  = $_POST['name'];
        $lastname  = $_POST['lastname'];

        $to = 'mpylla@gmail.com';
        $subject = 'From :'.$email;

        $message1 = 'From: '.$name."\nEmail: ".$email."\nMessage: ".$message;

        mail($to, $subject, $message1);

        }


        sendmail();
?>
```

and this ajax script is in my HTML code:

```
$("#submit").click(function(e) {

    var name = $("#name").val();
    var lastname = $("#lastname").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var message = $("#message").text();
    var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;

    if (!emailReg.test(email)) {
        alert('Ju lutem shkruan nje e-mail valide');
        return false;
    }

    if (email.length == 0) {
        alert("Email duhet te shenohet");
        return false;
    }

    if (name.length == 0) {
        alert("Emri duhet te shenohet");
        return false;
    }
    if (lastname.length == 0) {

        alert("Mbiemri duhet te shenohet");
        return false;
    }
    if (message.length == 5) {
        alert("Mesazhi duhet te shenohet");
        return false;
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "mail.php",
            data: $("#myform").serialize(),
            success: function(response) {
                $("#sukses").fadeIn('slow');
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $("#sukses").fadeOut('slow');
                    document.getElementById('myform').reset();
                }, 100);
                clearInterval();


            }
        });
    }




    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

});
```

Comment: The script doesn't send to spam, your mail provider/client did this. And there are various reasons for it, enough for you to do a proper research

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my e-mail still being picked up as spam? Using mail() function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515769/why-is-my-e-mail-still-being-picked-up-as-spam-using-mail-function)

Comment: I suggest you look around how to send headers for mail with php. that'll help you a lot :)

Comment: an aside: your email test will fail may legit email addresses

Comment: Because, you don't have proper headers and not having a `From: email@whatever.xxx` is one of them.

Answer (score -1):

This is usually down to the content of the email itself and the type of mailbox you are sending the email to.

Each have various spam filters in place to restrict malicious emails. Take a look [at this](http://mailchimp.com/resources/guides/how-to-avoid-spam-filters/html/) for some tips to help you.

Comment: Not my downvote, but what I think is really happening is that the OP doesn't have a `From:` with an email address nor proper headers. 9.9 times out of 10, will be treated as Spam or rejected altogether.